# Angular - Member 'console' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular

Below is my code in angular.  Simply trying to output to log an env var

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'angular';

  

  console.log( environment.API_URL);
}
```

However, I get the below error:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:3 - error TS7008: Member 'console' implicitly has an 'any' type.

12   console.log( environment.API_URL);
     ~~~~~~~
```

How do I resolve this?  Should not angular know its a object key?

Comment: You have a bare statement in a class. Typescript thinks you are trying to declare a property.

Comment: Instead, place it in a method.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments said, you have to place it in a method an and execute it.
Here an example using the Lifecycle and in addition the constructor:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  title = 'angular';

  constructor() {
    console.log( environment.API_URL);
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    console.log( environment.API_URL);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put the console log inside a function or in a lifecycle hook.